# using ViewModel in mvc to show data from multiple tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have MVC framework **User** Table and my own **Community** Table. I also have a relationship **CommunityUser** table. I am virtually connecting CommunityUser table with community Table.
Here is my **Community** class

```
public class Community
{
    [Key]
    public int CommunityID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CommunityName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CommunityDomain { get; set; }
    public string CommunityAbout { get; set; }
    public string CommunityLogo { get; set; }

    public int PrivacyID { get; set; }

    public string CommunityAdmin { get; set; }
    public virtual PrivacyLevel PrivacyLevel { get; set; }
    public virtual  ICollection<CommunityUser> CommunityUsers { get; set; }

    public Community()
    {
        CommunityUsers = new Collection<CommunityUser>();
    }
}
```

I want to use User Table and Community User Table on my index page. I have created a **ProfileDataViewModel** having these two tables.

```
public class ProfileDataViewModel
{
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public List<CommunityUser> CommunitiesList { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I am using this view model on my index function, it is throwing an exception. Here is my **index** function

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var thisUser = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).SingleOrDefault();

    var myDashboard = new ProfileDataViewModel()
    {
        User = thisUser,
        CommunitiesList = db.CommunityUsers.Include(x => x.Community).Where(u => u.UserID==thisUser.Id).ToList()

    };
    return View(myDashboard);
}
```

Comment: Which exception ?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: Have you checked out the inner exception as suggested in the parent exception?

Comment: Is there any mismatch in column names or foreign key mapping name between your model class and your actual DB table? That's a pretty standard reason for this error.

Comment: Can I show you my Identity model and and CommunityUser Model?